# Looking for a way to make a grid on the screen to help position elements

Tags: browser, browser-addons, css, grid, measurement

I'm working with CSS and at times it's hard to see if something's centred. Is there a program or some way built into a browser that I can make a grid appear on the screen? I'm using FireFox on Windows 7 but I'm willing to try a different browser.

Comment: I use the edge of a piece of paper, or a ruler. :)

Comment: There was absolutely no basis to close this question as an on-screen ruler meant for various purposes and a grid built into a browser to facilitate web design and CSS coding is not the same thing.

Comment: @DesmondHume that may be true but this question is still Off-Topic as it's a software rec.

Comment: @KronoS some problems inherently require a software solution, even you admit it http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software. If you know a solution that doesn't require software feel free to suggest it.

Comment: @Celeritas this is true, and I'm in no way saying that ALL questions that require software as a solution are off-topic.  At quick glance your question appeared to be asking "what's the best app to do x".  Upon closer examination I see that you're looking for a solution to a problem and not a query for "what's the best..."

Answer (score 1):

[GridFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/gridfox/) seems to be one of few solutions for this, or possibly the only one in existence.

It used to save gird setting for each domain but this feature is no longer working since the server it was saving settings to is down. So, to let GridFox make grids and save any settings, you'll have to go to **Tools > GridFox > Preferences** and check "Don't save grids for each domain" checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there's a way to set it so that the grid is made of squares? Or do I have to play with the settings until I guess it right?

Answer (score 0):

You could always make a transparent image with two edges colored and then tile it across the whole page with CSS while you're working on it. You'll have to add it to every page and then remove it when you're done, but it's a pretty easy solution.